# upgraded puppet 3 to 5. if I store a value in hiera as "D:\Temp\" it is taking "D:\\Temp\\"

Tags: puppet, hiera

In yaml file it is written as, `temp: D:\Temp\` ; 
While running it is taking as `D:\\\\Temp\\\\`

> debugging message:     Found key: "temp" value: "D:\\Temp\\"

Comment: used lookup function

Comment: And how did you generate the message?  Overall, can you present a [mcve]?